# Object function not working in JS

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object, functional-programming

This is a function for a simple shopping app (kinda) thing that I coded to work on my JS skills, considering my elementary experience in it. But everything works except for one thing:

The applyStaffDiscount function doesn't seem to work. Everytime I try to apply an employee discount, the program just returns the same original value that was present before trying to apply the discount. Please help and also let me know how I can improve this program.

```
function StaffMember(name, discountPercent) {
    this.name = name;
    this.discountPercent = discountPercent;
}

var sally = new StaffMember("sally", 5);
var bob = new StaffMember("bob", 10);
var arhum = new StaffMember("arhum", 20);

var cashRegister = {
    total: 0,
    lastTransactionAmount: 0,
    add: function(itemCost) {
        this.total += (itemCost || 0);
        this.lastTransactionAmount = itemCost;
    },
    scan: function(item, quantity) {
        switch (item) {
            case "eggs": this.add(0.98 * quantity); break;
            case "milk": this.add(1.23 * quantity); break;
            case "magazine": this.add(4.99 * quantity); break;
            case "chocolate": this.add(0.45 * quantity); break;
        }
        return true;
    },
    voidLastTransaction: function() {
        this.total -= this.lastTransactionAmount;
        this.lastTransactionAmount = 0;
    },
    applyStaffDiscount: function(employee) {
        this.total -= (this.total * (employee.discountPercent/100))
    }
};

    var cont = confirm("Are you ready to shop?")
    while (cont) {
        var user = ("Choose your function: A to Add Item, ED for Employee Discount, VT to Void Transaction or just X to Close")
        var askUser = prompt(user).toUpperCase()
        if (askUser === "A") {
            var itemName = prompt("What item would you like?", "Eggs, Milk, Magazine, Chocolate").toLowerCase()
            var itemNum = prompt("How many?")
            cashRegister.scan(itemName, itemNum)
            var cont = confirm("Your total bill is $" + cashRegister.total.toFixed(2) + ". Would you like anything else?")
        }
        else if (askUser === "ED") {
            var name1 = prompt("Please enter you name").toLowerCase()
            cashRegister.applyStaffDiscount[name1]
            alert("Your total bill is $" + cashRegister.total.toFixed(2) + ".")
}
        else if (askUser === "VT") {
            cashRegister.voidLastTransaction()
            alert("Your previous transaction has been voided. Your total bill is $" + cashRegister.total.toFixed(2) + " now.")
        }
        else if (askUser === "X") {
            cont = false
        }
        if (cont === false) {
            alert("We hope you had a good time. have a nice day!")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calling `applyStaffDiscount` should be done as shown below

```
cashRegister.applyStaffDiscount(name1);
```

Then inside `applyStaffDiscount`  function, it should be accessed as below

```
this.total -= (this.total * (window[employee].discountPercent/100))
```

Comment: Hi Oxi! Thanks for the edit, I'll try it out asap. Also, can you please explain why you changed it to that? You know, so I'd learn to avoid such mistakes in the future.

EDIT: It worked! The discount is now being applied! Thank you so much, Oxi. I've been trying to figure this out for a week.

Comment: @ArhumIshtiaq : `name1` is local variable, which contain nothing but a string (which happens to be the variable name of `employee object`). now again inside `applyStaffDiscount` function, the argument `employee` is string exactly like variable `name1` . so if you want to access an object in global scope(`window`) by using the name of the object, you try `window[employee]`. hope i explained it

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks so much! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call the function in here:

```
cashRegister.applyStaffDiscount[name1]
```

Try it with something like this:

```
cashRegister.applyStaffDiscount(name1);
```

Comment: That was actually what I was going for from the start but the program kept returning an undefined value.